# GateKeeper alert shows on few system

Tags: macos, osx-gatekeeper

I have an application that was built with xcode and packed using 'IceBerg' package maker. After making the package I used `codesign` command to code-sign the application. So I wouldn't get the 'un-indentified developer' message.

Recently one of our client complained about getting the 'un-indentified developer' message even though the Gatekeeper option is set to 'Map App Store and indentified developers'. It is happening only in this clients system.

What could be the reason? Do you have any advice?

Comment: This isn't an answer, just a suggestion. One of my colleagues often installs development packages on specific machines by targeting them in his apple development portal. He is an iPhone developer so it may not be the same for your enviroment, but might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "productsign" to sign your packages.
Please see [Gatekeeper Unreleased Notes](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Unreleased_Notes/10.8_Gatekeeper.html)